# Scroll roll event Firefox deltaX deltaY dimmis

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar, direction

I would like create dynamic scrollbar, scrolling via mouse rool/gesture.
I want detect axis event scroll. In other browsers (IE, opera, Chrome) `deltaX` `deltaY` working correctly, but FF have problem and support only `detail`.

For me is important to get 'size' scroll and I must use `delta_`. Default it is 100, but when in system mouse control I change scroll value, the `deltaX` also change value.

I spent many hours for resolve my problem, but I haven't idea, how get scroll direction in FF.

https://jsfiddle.net/ftnw63cv/

HTML:

```
<div class="wheelscroll">
scroll here
<div id="log">

</div>
</div>
<div class="y_scrollbar">
    <div>a</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
scrollbarWidth = function(){//calculate scrollbar size
    var a,b,c;
        if(c===undefined){
            a=$('<div style="width:50px;height:50px;overflow:auto"><div/></div>').appendTo('body');
            b=a.children();
            c=b.innerWidth()-b.height(99).innerWidth();
            a.remove();
        }
    return c;
};

$(function(){
  $('.y_scrollbar').css({'width':scrollbarWidth()+1+'px'});
  $('.y_scrollbar>div').css({'height':'5000px','width':scrollbarWidth()+'px'});

  scroll_rep_list = function(e){//scroll function
    console.log(e);
    if(e<0)
      $('.y_scrollbar').animate({scrollTop:'-='+Math.abs(e)+'px'},50);
    else
      $('.y_scrollbar').animate({scrollTop:'+='+e+'px'},50);
  }
  if(typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined'){//scroll event in FF
    $('.wheelscroll').on('MozMousePixelScroll', function(e){
      z = e.originalEvent.detail;
      $('#log').html('deltaY: '+e.originalEvent.deltaY+'<br>deltaX: '+e.originalEvent.deltaX);
      scroll_rep_list(z);

      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    });
  }
  else if(/*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode){//scroll event in IE
    $('.wheelscroll').on('wheel', function(e){
      z = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
      $('#log').html('deltaY: '+e.originalEvent.deltaY+'<br>deltaX: '+e.originalEvent.deltaX);
      scroll_rep_list(z);

      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    });
  }
  else
  {
    $('.wheelscroll').on('mousewheel', function(e){//scroll event for other
      z = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
      $('#log').html('deltaY: '+e.originalEvent.deltaY+'<br>deltaX: '+e.originalEvent.deltaX);
      scroll_rep_list(z);

      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    });
  }

});
```